# Brightness controls not working on a Sony Vaio VPCY2

Tags: brightness, vaio, sony

The brightness control are not working on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit , Sony Vaio VPCY2 ( Intel video card) .
I've tried both ways <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> and from Brightness/Lock menu (under Settings) - I can slide the brightness adjustment bar but nothing changes so it looks like the brightness controls are not working at all.

Anyone know if there is a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Open a terminal

2) type this:  gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

3) Enter your password;
   a text editor will appear, find the following lines:

```
Section "Screen"
       Identifier     "Screen0"
       Device         "Device0"
       Monitor        "Monitor0"
       DefaultDepth    24
       Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   SubSection     "Display"
       Depth       24
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

4) make this line look like this or add it if it dosen't exist:
   Option          "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"

5) close & save changes (Be careful before saving you can take down your system, if you're not sure that you didn't do anything wrong choose "don't save"!!

6) Restart computer.

Comment: There is no file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf in Ubuntu 12.10 , also there is not file xorg.conf on the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

I am Having Vaio VGN-FZ340E and it didn't work WITH THIS SOLUTION

AND SOLVED following this link

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11910629#post11910629

Comment: The Vaio VPCY2 does not have an NVIDA video board it has an Intel one.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for my Vaio VPCY2 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2086359