# How do I prevent Ubuntu from changing my laptop screen brightness level?

Tags: 12.04, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my dell inspiron 1464. Everything is working fine. Except my LED brightness.

Every time I adjust it to my suitable level. But after reboot it goes on high as it was before. This is quite irritating specially at night.

I do not face this problem in previous version. How can I lock my brightness to my preference?

Comment: Have a read of this 


http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11910629#post11910629

Comment: And this http://askubuntu.com/questions/128285/brightness-controls-not-working-on-a-sony-vaio-vpcy2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem on my Dell XPS. Currently there is no other way to save it according to brightness key.

- First try executing

  ```
  sudo su -c 'echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'
  ```

If it succed,try with different value for `5` and choose your preference level.

- Now edit `/etc/rc.local` file to execute this command at boot up.

  ```
  gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
  ```
- Just before `exit` in the file, add the following line,

  ```
  echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
  ```

You can change value `5` to anything.

Comment: You can use a shutdown script to save the last brightness setting from that file and then echo the saved value as above on startup.  Also, instead of the directory `acpi_video0` you might have a different one.  You can find the right path by using `ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`.

Comment: will try this definitely

Comment: Also, `sudoedit` is a better option compared to `gksu gedit` since `sudoedit` automatically fires up the user's default text editor. Kindly update your answer with this, and generaise it based on instructions given by ChanHoSuh.