# Contrast Getting Reset to its Maxmum Value After Restarting System

Tags: 12.04, hardware, dell, brightness

Recently i installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Laptop ***"Dell Inspiron-N4010"***.

i am facing problem with my contrast control,after restarting my system contrast is getting reset to its max value.

so each time after login have to set the contrast again & again.

Please advice ....

Regards,
Shiv Rajawat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working on my machine, but as soon as the greeter screen appears the brightness jumps right back to maximum, any other steps I could take to find out whats causing this and override it to make the lower setting stick?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on my Dell XPS. Currently there is no other way to save it according to brightness key.

- Find your brightness control path, execute

  ```
  ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
  ```

  the output will be something like `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`
- Copy that path and try executing

  ```
  sudo su -c 'echo 5 > THE_PATH_FROM_FIRST_COMMAND'
  ```

it will be like ->  `sudo su -c 'echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'`

If it succed,try with different value for `5` and choose your preference level.

- Now edit `/etc/rc.local` file to execute this command at boot up.

  ```
  gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
  ```
- Just before `exit` in the file, add the following line,

  ```
  echo 5 > THE_PATH_FROM_FIRST_COMMAND
  ```

You can change value `5` to anything.

Linked Question:

[How do I prevent Ubuntu from changing my laptop screen brightness level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134812/how-do-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-changing-my-laptop-screen-brightness-level/134820)

Comment: Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Hi Web E,
         as you told i run the command but i am getting two paths,please see

thethakur@thethakur-Inspiron-N4010:~$ ls /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
thethakur@thethakur-Inspiron-N4010:~$

should follow the same above steps or step will be change in my case...

Comment: any one.. I have the same problem. I use first one