# Screen brightness turns low

Tags: gnome, brightness

When I'm about 30 seconds with out doing nothing the brightness of the screen turns down to the minimum. When I restart doing something (just moving the mouse) goes back to the original brightness I had.

I have in Settings>Energy disabled the option that does that.

Is there any config file I should modify?

Using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Comment: The option is available in `Brightness and Lock`. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that option you said is the one I have deactivated, but it seems it doesn't work...

Comment: Don't leave, I am writing your answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install `dconf-editor` using the command `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`.
- Launch it by typing `dconf-editor` in the terminal or by using dash.
- Navigate to `org`>`gnome`>`settings-daemon`>`plugins`>`power`.
- There you will have option of changing the value of`idle-brightness`(Mine is 30).
- To turn off dimming of the screen uncheck `idle-dim`.

Comment: I had dconf-editor already installed cause I thought that the problem was there, but I couldn't find it.

I had idle-brightness as you and the idle-dim unchecked. I checked it and unchecked it... and now seems that the problem is solved...!

Thanks for your quick help ;)!

Comment: Anytime, brother.

Comment: Does the settings change, everytime you restart or the above solution didn't fix your problem.

Comment: The solution didn't work. I'm using now Caffeine. But I would like to have a solution without using it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134812/how-do-i-prevent-ubuntu-from-changing-my-laptop-screen-brightness-level?rq=1 can be the solution.