# Brightness control on Sony Vaio VPCY2 not working

Tags: brightness, sony

I have a sony vaio vpcy2 and the brightness control is not working. I tried the solution on [Brightness controls not working on a Sony Vaio VPCY2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128285/brightness-controls-not-working-on-a-sony-vaio-vpcy2) but it did not work for me.
Can someone help me out with another solution?

Answer (score 0):

LCD Brightness Control

Once you have installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers as suggested above, you may notice that your brightness control keys do not work properly. This is fixable by editing one's xorg.conf file. Open a terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Append a line so it appears like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You will need to restart your graphical server (or reboot) for this change to take effect.

Comment: I tried that too (had to create my own xorg.cong file with X -configure), but even that did not help me out.